# Prove that if $AC^T = |A|I \implies \det C = (\det A)^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Prove that if $AC^T = |A|I \implies \det C = (\det A)^{n-1}$

Ran into trouble with a proof for linear algebra. $C$ is the cofactor matrix of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and I'm not sure how to even approach this problem. Any tips for starting? Not the entire proof, please.

Comment: Prove that if $AC^T = |A|I \implies detC = (det A)^{n-1}$ then what? Is $n$ any arbitrary non-negative integer?

Comment: @GitGud I think it should be read without the "if", and only with the implication arrow.

Comment: @GitGud: I suspect that the OP means "Prove that if $AC^T=|A|I$, then $\det C=(\det A)^{n-1}.$"

Comment: I assumed so too. My comment was a hint to his mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$\det(AC^T)=\det(A)\det(C^T) =\det(A)\det(C)$$

What is $\det(\alpha I)$, for any scalar $\alpha$?

If $\det(A)=0$, note that $AC^T=CA^T =0_{n\times n}$. What does this say about the nullspace of $C$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\det(A) = 0$, one entire row or column of the cofactor matrix must be zero by the definition of $\det(A)$ and thus $$\det(C) = 0 = 0^{n-1} = \det(A)^{n-1}.$$ If $\det(A) \neq 0$, then $$\det(A C^T) = \det(A) \det(C^T) = \det(A) \det(C)$$
and $$\det(|A|I) = |A|^n \det(I) = \det(A)^n.$$ By assumption these are equal and so dividing both sides by $\det(A)$ gives the desired result.

Comment: What if $A=0$ and $n=1$?

Comment: If $A = 0$, then the cofactor matrix is also zero and so $\det(C) = 0 = 0^0 = \det(A)^{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm confused with $0=0^0$.

Comment: $0^0 = 0$ since $0$ to any power is always $0$. Also, please see my edit above. I realized that case $\det(A) = 0$ was not so obvious.

Comment: I would ask what your definition of 'power' is because I don't know why $0=0^0$, but until the OP clarifies the range of $n$, this discussion isn't suitable here.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean. Well, if $n \geq 2$, then the proof is definitely okay?

Comment: I think so, yes. I'd upvote if that clarification was to be made.

Comment: Your first step is incorrect. Consider $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 &1 \\ 1 &1\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Indeed. You are correct. I'll try to fix this.